# Why is my AJAX running 4 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oG8p.png

```
$("#login").on('click', function () {
    $(".login .col2, .login .signin, .login .close").fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(".login .spinner").fadeIn(500);
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#pw").val();
        var data = "username="+username+"&password="+password;
        $.ajax({
            url: './api/prijava',
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.odg == 1) {
                    $(".login .spinner").fadeOut(500, function() {
                        $(".login .msg").append('Prijava uspješna').fadeIn(500, function() {
                            window.location = "./";
                        });
                    });
                } else if(data.odg == 2) {
                    $(".login .msg").css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)').append('<span>Prijava uspješna! Dobrodošli...</span>').fadeIn(500, function() {
                        window.location = "./?first=true";
                    }); 
                }
            }, 
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Screenshot shows successful login (local language) but it should show it once, rather than 4 times. How can I make it load once and that's it?

Comment: .fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] ) It's running during completion of fadeOut for each of the items that match the selector ".login .col2, .login .signin, .login .close"  which i would have to assume if it's running 4 times there are 4 matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback to `fadeOut` will run once per selected element. Instead you could use the `promise` to since when it resolves it only runs once:

```
$(selector).fadeOut(500).promise().then(function () {
    // do ajax call here
});
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response, forgot to mark it as answer :D